# how form data in attachment Word in E-mail

Tags: php, phpmailer, phpword

I have two things. I have phpmailer, he sent the content of the form to a E-mailaddress, this works. And I have phpword, he make word file, this also works.

I have a question; how can I get the content of the form the $message (Full name, subject, phone, email and comments) in a Word(docx) file in a Email attachment if you click on the submit button?

With this code you see nothing in the browser, how can I 'mix' phpmailer and phpword?.

Can someone help me?

thanks in advance.

The form code is:

```
    <?php
//phpword

require_once '../PHPWord.php';

// New Word Document
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// New portrait section
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

$section->addText($message, array('name'=>'Verdana', 'color'=>'006699'));
$section->addTextBreak(2);


// Save File
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('Text.docx');



//phpmailer
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$message=
'Full Name:    '.$_POST['fullname'].'<br />
Subject:    '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
Phone:    '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />
Email:    '.$_POST['emailid'].'<br />
Comments:    '.$_POST['comments'].'
';
    require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

    // Instantiate Class  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  

    // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "test@gmail.com"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "secret"; // Your Gmail password

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->Subject = "form from website";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress("test@gmail.com", "form from website"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();        // Send!  
    $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
    unset($mail);

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin: 100px auto 0;width: 300px;">
            <h3>Contact Form</h3>
            <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required/>
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email"  required/>
                      <br />
                      <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Question/Comments"></textarea>
                      <br />
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
                    </fieldset>
            </form>
            <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically you are trying to add the content of the variable `$message` to the word document BEFORE you even declared it.

Also, you don't define an "action" in your form, so it is just doing nothing when you click the submit button.

Assuming that the rest of your code works, this should do it:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

     //phpword
     require_once '../PHPWord.php';

     //phpmailer
     require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

     $message=
     'Full Name:    '.$_POST['fullname'].'<br />
     Subject:    '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
     Phone:    '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />
     Email:    '.$_POST['emailid'].'<br />
     Comments:    '.$_POST['comments'].'
     ';

     // New Word Document
     $PHPWord = new PHPWord();

     // New portrait section
     $section = $PHPWord->createSection();
     $section->addText($message, array('name'=>'Verdana', 'color'=>'006699'));
     $section->addTextBreak(2);

     // Save File
     $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
     $objWriter->save('Text.docx');    

    // Instantiate Class  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  

    // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "test@gmail.com"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "secret"; // Your Gmail password

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->Subject = "form from website";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress("test@gmail.com", "form from website"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();        // Send!  
    $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
    unset($mail);

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin: 100px auto 0;width: 300px;">
            <h3>Contact Form</h3>
            <form name="form1" id="form1" action="url.php" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required/>
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email"  required/>
                      <br />
                      <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Question/Comments"></textarea>
                      <br />
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
                    </fieldset>
            </form>
            <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember to replace "url.php" with the real URL of your page.

Regards

**EDIT:**
In order to be able to attach the Word file with phpmailer and reading the documentation (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial):

> The command to attach a local file is simply
>   $mail->addAttachment($path);, where $path contains the path to the
>   file you want to send, and can be placed anywhere between $mail = new
>   PHPMailer; and sending the message. Note that you cannot use a URL for
>   the path - you may only use local filesystem path. See notes on string
>   attachments below for how to use remote content.

Translated to your script, this means you have to add the following line:

```
[...]
$mail->AddAddress("test@gmail.com", "form from website"); // Where to send it - Recipient
$mail->addAttachment("Text.docx"); // <--------------------------
$result = $mail->Send();        // Send!
```

Comment: yes, I see it, isset in top of the page. But I want to have a attachment in the E-mail, how can I make this with: $mail->AddAttachment($message);      // attachment??                                    thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean to add the newly created Word file rather that the variable itself. If so, look at the edit above.